# Improving a method adding BigIntegers

Tags: java

So earlier today I wrote a method for personal uses that sums the integers given as arguments:

```
public class BigSum {
    public static int sum(int... numbers) {
        int sum = 0;
        for(int n : numbers) {
            sum += n;
        }
        return sum;
    }
}
```

Later, it turned out that int value is too small for the purposes of my program, so I switched to BigIntegers. I decided it would be easier if the method took Strings as arguments, converted them to BigIntegers and then summed them:

```
import java.math.*;

public class BigSum {
    public static BigInteger sum(String... numbers) {
        BigInteger sum = BigInteger.ZERO;
        for(String n : numbers) {
            BigInteger x = new BigInteger(n);
            sum = sum.add(x);
    }
        return sum;
}
}
```

The only problem with this code is that you need to give arguments between double quotes (since it takes Strings), and it's usually very inconvenient.
What can I do for `sum` method to take arguments like this:

```
BigInteger NUMBER = BigSum.sum(5, 6);
```

Instead of:

```
BigInteger NUMBER = BigSum.sum("5", "6");
```

?

Comment: You could take `long` or `double`. There's no syntax for a `BigInteger` literal.

Answer (score 3):

You can accept `Object...` as an arguments and use the `toString()` method:

```
public static BigInteger sum(Object... numbers) {
    BigInteger sum = BigInteger.ZERO;
    for(Object n : numbers) {
        BigInteger x = new BigInteger(n.toString());
        sum = sum.add(x);
    }
    return sum;
}
// ...
BigInteger sum1 = BigSum.sum("5", 6); // 11
// With a real big integer
BigInteger sum2 = BigSum.sum("1234567891011121314151617181920", 1);
// 1234567891011121314151617181921
```

This code will throw a `NumberFormatException` if the number is not a valid representation of a BigInteger.

Comment: This would require that the arguments to the `sum` method be String literals, which is exactly what the OP asked to avoid.

Comment: It works great, but compiler refuses to add values beyond the range of `int`. Object can't be bigger than `int`? I don't get it.

Comment: @Bobulous No, you can pass String or int indifferently. I added an example.

Comment: No matter: it turns out the component parts are too large to be held in primitive types anyway.

Comment: Well yes. You cannot represent an integer as an ``int`` if it is bigger than ``2^31-1``. That is why ``BigInteger`` accepts ``String``...

Answer (score 1):

Before you resort to using `BigInteger` check to make sure that you can't simply use the `long` primitive type. The `long` type holds much larger values than the `int` primitive type and won't require the overhead of creating `BigInteger` objects.

However, if your sums will grow to sizes beyond the capacity of `long` but your individual parts do fit in the `long` type then you could switch your method to take an array of `long` values and then use a `BigInteger` to hold the total. Such a method might look like this:

```
public static BigInteger sum(long... numbers) {
    BigInteger total = BigInteger.ZERO;
    for(long number : numbers) {
        total = total.add(BigInteger.valueOf(number));
    }
    return total;
}
```

Comment: I did consider long, but its range is still too small for me.

Comment: Even for the component parts?

Comment: Yes, I needed something that can store numbers with ~50 digits.

Comment: @shooqie Then you have to use `String`.

Comment: If your component parts you want to feed to the `sum` method cannot be held in a `long` then you will need to pass `String` literals or `BigInteger` objects to that method. So you cannot simply call the method with parameters which are primitive types like you were hoping. Please edit your question to clarify this point, as it's not clear.

Answer (score 0):

You may change your class like this -

```
public static BigInteger sum(BigInteger... numbers) {

   BigInteger sum = BigInteger.ZERO;

   for(BigInteger n : numbers) {
        BigInteger x = new BigInteger(n);
        sum = sum.add(x);
 }
```

Comment: If the OP finds `BigSum.sum("5", "6");` inconvenient then I'm sure they find `BigSum.sum(BigInteger.valueOf("5"), BigInteger.valueOf("6"))` even more inconvenient.

Comment: `BigInteger x = new BigInteger(n);` What? You create a new `BigInteger` from an existing `BigInteger`, because ...?